# Linux kernel, where is the task_struct (process) initialization

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a homework where I must add some entries to the `task_struct` and do some things with them. Also, I must initialize an entry to a specific int when the `task_struct` initialize.

Where is the file/code that `task_struct` does its first initialization?

I found `INIT_TASK.h` but there is the first process of the `task_struct` table. I want to find where each `task_struct` initializes and defines it's starting values in order to define some numbers to the new entries I inserted.

Comment: As this is your homework, we can only give you a bunch of hints. Which system call is used for creating new processes? Where it's defined in kernel sources? Once you know its location, you can look at how `task_struct` is being initialized (in code). Also, when you know that system call name, you can use Google to find an explanation on how `task_struct` is initialized in it. You can use [LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) to navigate the kernel code. Good luck.

Comment: I do not know which system call is used. I tried fork, do_fork, init_task but I could not find something except init_task.h as I said in my first post. Could you please just tell me either the syscall either the file that I can find the code for task_struct initialization? This is the only thing that I miss in my assignment as I have finished all others.

Comment: That is correct. `fork()` system call is used for creating processes, as can be seen from [man 2 fork](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). Now, using `grep` tool, find where `fork` syscall is defined in kernel. Hint: look for `SYSCALL_DEFINE0` macro, as `fork()` takes 0 arguments. Kernel sources can be obtained either from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/) (use **mainline** kernel), or you can use LXR, as suggested earlier. Hint #2 (as discussed above): use `fork` and `task_struct` keywords to google for explanation; then search for `task_struct` in found pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried fork, do_fork, init_task but I could not find something except
>   init_task.h as I said in my first post. Could you please just tell me
>   either the syscall either the file that I can find the code for
>   task_struct initialization?

You were already on the right track. Now `do_fork()` as well as the function behind the `SYSCALL_DEFINE0(fork)` calls `_do_fork()`, which calls `copy_process()`, where the new `struct task_struct *p` is created by `p = dup_task_struct(current, node);` - thereafter, `copy_process()` would be a good place for your additions. All this is in the file [`kernel/fork.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/fork.c#L2015).